# How to make assign always the value 1 to the LAST "row_id" created

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a mysql table and the first column names "row_id" and contains an number that shows the id of the row created into the table.

Here below a very simple an example made easier:

```
+--------+---------+------+---------+------+-----------+
| row_id | user_id | city | zipcode | note | imagepath |
+--------+---------+------+---------+------+-----------+
| 1      |         |      |         |      |           |
| 2      |         |      |         |      |           |
| 3      |         |      |         |      |           |
| 4      |         |      |         |      |           |
+--------+---------+------+---------+------+-----------+
```

I would like to know if there is a way, into the phpmyadmin console, to be able to make assign always the value 1 to the LAST "row_id" created, making become as 2 the previous "row_id" that was 1, making become as 3 the previous "row_id" that was 2, and so on.

Thank you very much.

Comment: what do you want to achieve by this...in this way if your table has 1 lacs rows then you will be updating 1 lacs rows..is it practical.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
UPDATE my_table SET row_id = row_id + 1; INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 5, 'fourth_city', 'fourth_zipcode', 'fourth_note', 'fourth_image');
UPDATE my_table SET row_id = row_id + 1; INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 6, 'fifth_city', 'fifth_zipcode', 'fifth_note', 'fifth_image');
```

.... And so on

But if row_id is your primary key then you must drop it before:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PRIMARY KEY;
UPDATE my_table SET row_id = row_id + 1; INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 5, 'fourth_city', 'fourth_zipcode', 'fourth_note', 'fourth_image');
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD PRIMARY KEY(row_id);

ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PRIMARY KEY;
UPDATE my_table SET row_id = row_id + 1; INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 6, 'fifth_city', 'fifth_zipcode', 'fifth_note', 'fifth_image');
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD PRIMARY KEY(row_id);
```

.... And so on.

You can create a stored procedure or function to simplify the call. Hope help.

Comment: Hi Pieter,I thank you for your reply. If I try your code I have tu put manually the values 'fifth_city', 'fifth_zipcode', 'fifth_note', 'fifth_image'. Instead, I would need to perform a permanent and fixed modification into the phpmyadmin console, just once, in order to leave the php web site work automatically by adding new rows. How can I do it just making a single modification into the phpmyadmin console? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure about what do you want. I always use stored procedure and function to automate MySQL. Really hope to help if you want, to create a function may be. But please explain to me the detail, do you want to create an automatic button in phpmyadmin console, make a web site with the function or something?

Comment: Hi Pieter, first of all I thank you for your support. I have a php web site in which the registered users can add new items, for examle they can create a new "event". Into a specific page, I want that the last event created is always shown. For example: if "John" has created 10 minutes a go an event named "First event" and Bob has created 5 minutes a go another event named "Second event", this last is the event that has to be shown on the page. To do this, I need to make the web site read always the value into the last row_id, the last row_id is the row containing the last event created.Thanks

Comment: Or you could just do `MAX(id)` ? I think you're making this harder than it needs to be.